# Как привести всё к базовому типу

Tags: c#, .net, ооп

Не могу понять как правильно реализовать метод `DataToBytes`.
Есть базовый абстрактный класс `Data<T>` и два наследника: `DataSting` (от `Data<string>`) и `DataInt` (от `Data<int>`).

Мне нужна функция, которая принимает любые классы, унаследованные от `Data`. Код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
                    
public class Program
{
    public abstract class Data<T>
    {
        public T Value {get; set;}
        
        public abstract byte[] ToBytes();
    }
    
    public sealed class DataInt : Data<int>
    {
        public override byte[] ToBytes()
        {
            return new byte[0]; // представим, что здесь какае-то логика
        }
    }
    
    public sealed class DataString : Data<string>
    {       
        public override byte[] ToBytes()
        {
            return new byte[0]; // представим, что здесь тоже какае-то логика
        }
    }
    
    public static byte[] DataToBytes<T>(params Data<T>[] data)
    {
        var bytes = new List<byte>();
        
        foreach (var dataObject in data)
            bytes.AddRange(dataObject.ToBytes());
        
        return bytes.ToArray();
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {       
        var intData = new DataInt() { Value = 1 };
        var stringData = new DataString() { Value = "abc" };
        var bytes = DataToBytes(intData, stringData); // ошибка компиляции
    }
}
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, что можно сделать класс Data<object> и приводить всё к нему, но это выглядит костылём

Comment: Ну согласно тому что вы написали, все параметры должны быть одноготтипа. Какую именно задачу вы решаете? А то по коду с ходу не понятно, приведите пример практического применения, если можно. Какие именно типы вы хотите поддерживать?

Comment: добавь интерфейс с методом, `byte[] ToBytes()` и передавай его

Comment: @aepot мне нужно реализовать метод DataToBytes, так что бы он принимал любых наследников Data<T>

Comment: Дополнительно я бы посоветовал вам обратить внимание на классы `BinaryReader` и `BinaryWriter`. Ну и неплохо было бы знать, что за зверь такой `BinaryFormatter` несмотря на то, что он злой и опасный настолько, что его решили выпилить из .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, можно добавить интерфейс

```cs
public class Program
{
    public interface IData
    {
        public byte[] ToBytes();
    }

    public abstract class Data<T> : IData
    {
        public T Value { get; set; }
        
        public abstract byte[] ToBytes();
    }
    
    //...
    
    public static byte[] DataToBytes<T>(params IData[] data)
    {
        using var ms = new MemoryStream();
        
        foreach (IData dataObject in data)
            ms.Write(dataObject.ToBytes());
        
        return ms.ToArray();
    }

    //...
}
```

Да, кстати, `MemoryStream` здесь пошустрее отработает, чем `List`.